# Seeking Explanation of the Powershell ExpandProperty behaviour

Tags: powershell, properties, return-value, acl, expand

I'm just curious and looking for an explanation for the behaviour of the `expandProperty` switch.

Sometimes:

```
some-command | select-object property1, property2 -expand property3
```

Will give:

```
Property1 Property2 property3
aaaaaaa   bbbbbb    c
aaaaaaa   bbbbbb    d
```

But, sometimes you get:

```
Property3
c
d
```

Real examples that illustrate the above:

```
Get-Acl | select PSChildname, owner -ExpandProperty Access
```

and

```
Get-Acl | select PSChildname, owner -ExpandProperty AccessToString
```

So I believe that the difference is that in the first example it is returning an object and in the second it's just a set of values.  What I do not understand is why this makes a difference to the output?

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory reference to the docs on [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)

> Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property. Wildcards are permitted in the property name.
>
> For example, if the specified property is an array, each value of the array is included in the output. If the property contains an object, the properties of that object are displayed in the output.

The behavior of the parameter is dependent on the specified properties ***type***.

In your first example you expand `access` which is an array of `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` which fits this description:

> If the property contains **an object**, the properties of that object are displayed in the output.

In your second example `AccessToString` is a single string or scalar. While I cannot find anything definitive it seems that PowerShell supersedes any reference to `-Property`.

---

This is covered some on [blogs.msdn.microsoft.com](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishinde/2012/08/27/expandproperty-in-select-object/) as well.

> If you apply ExpandProperty to a property which is not a collection, it gives you just the values not the object with properties.

So that agrees with what we have been seeing just not about the presence of the other specified properties when we use `-Expand` on non collection properties.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, but the presence of the other properties is really the crux of my enquiry :-)

Comment: @AlNapp I thought I tried to answer that though. The crux is your choice of property. Between collections and scalars. That defines the behavior. I will see if I can find more of what I am looking for.